# Defining XSD to validate groups of permitted XML attributes for the same element

Tags: xml, xsd

I would like to define an XSD that would validate the following XML.

```
<parameters>
    <param name="Maximum Error Threshold" type="integer">10</param>
    <param name="Auto Shutdown Timeout Duration" type="integer" unit="seconds">300</param>
    <param name="Flow Rate Adjusment" type="integer" unit="litrePerSec">0.5</param>
    <param name="Configuration Download Time" type="timeofday" format="timestring">03:20</param>
    <param name="Maximum Issue Value" type="integer" unit="cents" format="numericfloat">145.50</param> 
</parameters>
```

I currently have a schema which looks something like:

```
  <xs:element name="parameters">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="5" minOccurs="5" ref="param"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="param">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:NMTOKEN">
          <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" type="AttributeNames"/>
          <xs:attribute name="type" use="required" type="AttributeTypes"/>
          <xs:attribute name="format" use="optional" type="AttributeFormats"/>
          <xs:attribute name="unit" use="optional" type="AttributeUnits"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:simpleType name="AttributeNames">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
      <xs:enumeration value="Maximum Error Threshold"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Auto Shutdown Timeout Duration"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Flow Rate Adjusment"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Configuration Download Time"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Maximum Issue Value"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="AttributeTypes">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:NCName">
      <xs:enumeration value="integer"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="timeofday"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="AttributeFormats">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:NCName">
      <xs:enumeration value="timestring"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="numericfloat"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="AttributeUnits">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:NCName">
      <xs:enumeration value="seconds"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="litrePerSec"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="cents"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

This works. But it does not give me complete validation. 
I would like to ensure that the appropriate attributes are present in the **'param'** element (and that these attributes contain the appropriate values), depending on what the **'name'** attribute contains.

For example;

If the **'name'** attribute = "Auto Shutdown Timeout Duration", then the **'type'** is required and can only be "integer" and the **'unit'** is required and can be "hours", "minutes" or "seconds".

But if **'name'** attribute = "Maximum Error Threshold", then the **'type'** is required and can only be "integer" but **'unit'** is not permitted.

So I decided to describe each parameter separately; i.e. something like:

```
  <xs:complexType name="MaxErrorParam">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:NMTOKEN">
        <xs:attribute name="name" fixed="Maximum Error Threshold"/>
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="CounterParameterAttributes"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="AutoShutdownParam">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:NMTOKEN">
        <xs:attribute name="name" fixed="Auto Shutdown Timeout Duration"/>
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="TimeOutParameterAttributes"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:attributeGroup name="CounterParameterAttributes">
    <xs:attribute name="type" use="required" fixed="integer"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup>

  <xs:attributeGroup name="TimeOutParameterAttributes">
    <xs:attribute name="type" use="required" fixed="integer"/>
    <xs:attribute name="format" use="required" type="TimeUnitsType"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup>

  <xs:simpleType name="TimeUnitsType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:NCName">
      <xs:enumeration value="minutes"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="seconds"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="hours"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

But this meant that i needed to define the **'param'** element as follows; this causes an error because the element **'param'** is defined twice with different type.

```
  <xs:element name="parameters">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="param" type="MaxErrorParam"/>
        <xs:element name="param" type="AutoShutdownParam"/>
        etc...
      </xs:>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Can anyone please suggest a solution or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Nobody has answered this, I hope it's still interesting to you. The approaches you outlined do not work: XML Schema cannot validate constraints of the form "if element X contains something then check Y". Also, you cannot have two elements with the same name but different types in the same container, as you said.

However, you what you **can** do is to 1) create a child element in param with a name of `value` and a type of  `xs:anySimpleType` and 2) use the native XML Schema type override mechanism (xsi:type):

```
<parameters xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <param name="Maximum Error Threshold">
        <value xsi:type="xs:int">10</value>
    </param>
</parameters>
```